# What strategies are used for annotation scanning in practice?

Tags: java, spring, reflection, annotations, bytecode

I am aware of the below mentioned ways in which annotations could be detected and used:

1. Annotation processors (compile time code generation)
2. Runtime annotation scanning (e.g. ASM and other byte-code scanning libraries)
3. Custom Class-loaders that reflect annotations on classes that they load
4. Using the reflection API at runtime

Note: I am not sure if method (3) is ever used

I am looking for information on what techniques of annotation processing are used in what kind of scenarios. A few examples that come to mind are:

1. Deployment time (E.g. how do Java EE containers know if annotations are correctly applied when you deploy a WAR)
2. Compile time (E.g. Apache Beehive Pageflows generates lots of XML files during compile time using annotation processors)
3. Runtime (E.g. Spring does byte-code annotation scanning on class paths you specify)

Answer (score 2):

4 is used heavily by dependency injection frameworks, such as `HK2` and `Guice`.

3 is actually used anywhere you care about dependency injection / initialization on static members of classes, such as with `PowerMock` to know if it needs to process the classes.